# How WP works with DB during cron job running?

Tags: wp-cron, import, debug

I have to create script for daily import data from external source to WordPress website.
It worked fine on my local machine. But when I run this import on wpengine, I get duplicate entries despite validation. It seems that some cron events are triggered twice because of low traffic. This has been fixed by switching to Alternate cron.

**But here is my question:**
Is there some mechanism to isolate the db while a cron job is running? Something like in Laravel Queues

This may explain why a duplicate job run did not see any changes on the database